# How to send a GET request in html

Tags: html, ajax

Is this possible? If not what are some alternatives..

Simply I want to send a GET request to

```
 //steamgaug.es/api/v2

"ISteamClient": {
        "online": 1
    },
```

and have it respond to this i.e

```
if ISteamClient online:1
```

then make it do something

Comment: Without using an `HTML` form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible with HTML. But it is definitely possible with Javascript, which you can add to any HTML code.

For code example please refer to [this stackoverflow thread!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript)

Your code will probably look like this:

```
<html>
<body>

<script>
var text = httpGet("https://steamgaug.es/api/v2");

obj = JSON.parse(text);

alert(obj.ISteamClient.online);

function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false ); // false for synchronous request
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```